# Is it possible to adjust Lightroom settings with scroll wheel

Tags: macos, adobe-lightroom

I'm using **Mac OS X 10.7.2 "Lion"** and **Adobe Lightroom 3.5**. On Windows, it was possible to adjust settings in the *Develop* module (exposure, contrast,...) by clicking on that setting and using the scroll wheel.

On my Mac, this doesn't work. Does anyone know if I can enable this?

Comment: I'm using the same setup on the Mac with a Magic Mouse and I can't make it work. Frankly, I've always hated Lightroom's sliders and when I need very fine adjustments I type numbers in the corresponding fields. It sucks as a work around but it does allow for very fine adjustments. Adobe doesn't even allow clicking on the ends of sliders to move them. The effect of Lightroom's tools is great but using them (the UI) is not great. If Aperture had Lightroom's tools I'd migrate to it but in fact, it's just not as good at noise reduction and the rest of it. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is easily possible to use your scroll wheel to adjust. The only way I can think of is writing a script that translates your scroll wheel action to a up and down arrow key action. but that would prevent you from using your wheel for other actions.

Possible alternative options are:

- Clicking on the number besides the slider and by holding your (left) mouse button and moving your mouse you can now adjust the slider.
- Click on the number then change the number with your keyboard arrow(up/down) keys. This works best for fine adjustments.
- Click on the slider then change the slider with tour keyboard arrow(up/down) keys. This works best for making somewhat bigger adjustments.

Comment: Clicking on the number besides the slider and by holding your (left) mouse button and moving your mouse you can now adjust the slider. -> That's a great workaround, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

use usb overdrive software...its incredible to do this!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on what USB Overdrive does? Or at the very least provide a link to it. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.